# How to use SLAB memory allocation instead of SLUB allocation in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, memory, virtual-memory

As I understand it, both SLAB and SLUB are still integrated into the kernel in stable release 5.12. Is there a way to enable SLAB allocation to run on the system instead of SLUB allocation? Or is there no “toggle” to switch between them/it doesn’t work like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no toggle in runtime: you switch between SLAB and SLUB (and if you enable EXPERT mode, [SLOB](https://www.programmersought.com/article/89117303175/#the-slob-allocator)) by recompiling the kernel. The option is in "General setup->Choose SLAB allocator".

I haven't found any reason to change from the default, but the answer to [this previous SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470560/what-to-choose-between-slab-and-slub-allocator-in-linux-kernel) indicates that there's probably little or no reason to use SLAB.